# Making executable all PHP files (recursively)

Tags: php, bash, chmod

I just downloaded MediaWiki software on my server for installation. After decompressing it, I noticed that PHP files were not executable.

I ran chmod `+x *.php*` (there are also .php5 files) but it didn't work in subdirectories.

How can I add the executable flag to all PHP scripts inside the MediaWiki folder recursively scanning the subfolders?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you need to make all files executable. Ordinary php include scripts don't need the flag. It's only advised for commandline scripts. Hence use a few `chmod +x */*.php` and `chmod +x */*/*.php` only in the appropriate tools folder.

Comment: @mario, if I recall correctly it's a possible (though probably uncommon) server setup that makes use of the "X Bit Hack".

Comment: You should always qualify your chmod commands. `chmod a+x *.php*` will set the execute bit for user, group and world. This is implicitly what you're doing anyway, but clearer. You may only need to set executable for user and group (`chmod ug+x`) depending on your situation, and if this will work you should do it that way.

Comment: For security reasons I would avoid using `a` or `o` (or implying `a` by leaving a qualifier out). It's safer to have `ug+x,o-x`

Comment: Sorry Dennis, but since Apache runs as wwwrun, it is **required** for scripts to be executable by others

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use bash in the MediaWiki directory

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs chmod +x
```

Comment: To make sure it works for filenames with spaces in it, use:  
  
`find . -iname '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod +x`

Comment: Right. Naming your files using white characters is bad ;) I hoped MediaWiki is a good software.

Comment: In fact, Robert's comment doesn't apply to MediaWiki, but is a good thing to remember for general usage

Answer (score 2):

It does not work in subdirectories, because `*.php*` does not match any directories and hence does not include it.

Therefore you should use something like `find ./ -iname "*.php*" -exec chmod 755 {} \;` with the respective bits to set.

Comment: Because chmod can operate on multiple files at once and because this operation will not fail when done in parallel you should be using `+` instead of `\;` to close your `-exec`.

Comment: '*.php*' was thought to match .php and .php5, not subdirectories ;)

Comment: Don't use `+` when you have no idea on the amount of the items in the resulting list. This will introduce a Bohrbug into your script. If the list is big enough, you will exceed the maximum length of the executable command line (OK, I know it is larger than 2 Mbytes, but it is still unsafe)

Comment: @djechelon: Of course it was thougth to match ".php" and ".php5", but your problem was that it didn't work for subdirectories. Nevertheless a subdirectory named "subdir" (including several files ending with ".php" or ".php5" itself) won't be considered, simply because "subdir" does not match "*.php*". Therefore the executable bit is not set for "*.php*"-files in "subdir"  ... ;)